# ClearCase - Find invisible versions of elements under a certain path

Tags: find, clearcase, cleartool

I am trying to find all versions on a particular branch, but the config spec of my working view should not matter (I want to work in a view with `/main/LATEST`).
I am working on Windows. Assuming that the version has been created before 27.May.17:47 and I don't want to see the 0 version on my branch.

I tried to do that by using `cleartool find`:

```
cleartool find M:\my_view.dv\MY_VOB\folder_x\folder_y\ -version "brtype(my_branch) && ! created_since(27-May.17:47) && ! version(...\my_branch\0)" -print
```

That works for all elements that have got at least a version `\main\1` or later from which the element has been branched off to my_branch.
But for an element which has just got version `\main\0` (because it has been created with a rule like "`element * \main\0 -mkbranch my_branch`") it does not work.

So I tried using another cleartool find with "`-nvisible`", but "`-nvisible`" does not work without "`-all`". So I have to use following:

```
cleartool find M:\my_view.dv\MY_VOB\folder_x\folder_y\ -all -nvisible -version "brtype(my_branch) && ! created_since(27-May.17:47) && ! version(...\my_branch\0)" -print
```

But because of the "`-all`" option my path "`M:\my_view.dv\MY_VOB\folder_x\folder_y\`" is completely ignored. Instead of just searching in my path it is searching the whole VOB, which is not what I want. Because it also gives me files under "`M:\my_view.dv\MY_VOB\folder_z\`" as result.

So I either need to modify first query that it will give me also elements that have been created with "`element * \main\0 -mkbranch my_branch`", or I need a second query that gives me elements that have been created with "`element * \main\0 -mkbranch my_branch`" under a certain path only...

Any idea how to solve the problem without an additional script?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [query language](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/query_language.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-6-9&lang=en) used by [`cleartool find`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-14&lang=en), you can use **compound queries**

```
query && query
query || query ! query ( query )
```

That means you could try and select:

- any version but the `mybranch/0`: `! version(...\my_branch\0)`
- OR:
- any version 0 which does not have a version 1: `version(...\my_branch\0) && ! version(...\my_branch\1)`

Something like:

```
brtype(my_branch) && ! created_since(27-May.17:47) && \
( ! version(...\my_branch\0)
  || \
  ( version(...\my_branch\0) && ! version(...\my_branch\1) ) \
)
```

To be complete, that might select the version 0 of a file for which multiple versions have been created on `mybranch`, but the version 1 have been deleted (`rmver`).
I don't think this would be *too* frequent though.

Comment: @Jonas I thought you wanted to avoid the `.../myBranch/0` version (unless the `0` version is the only one on `myBranch`)

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to get a list of all element versions on a branch "my_branch" under a certain path only, but the view and its config spec should not matter. So it does not matter what kind of query I use because if the element itself is not selected by the view I am using to run the cleartool find, then it won't give me any of its versions as a result. If an element has just got version `/main/0` but also a version `.../my_branch/1` then it is not selected by a view with a config spec `element * CHECKEDOUT \ element * /main/LATEST`, so even if the query itself would list that element, it will anyway not be processed because of the view does not select it...
So the solution should be to add `-nvisible`, so all elements will be processed even if they are not selected by the views config spec. But to add `-nvisible` without adding `-all` too is not possible... As soon as I add `-all` the find command will ignore my given path and search the whole VOB.